# Союз "и" между придаточными и запятая

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

*Он  прекрасно знает, что я слежу за ним и что это его испытание.*

Нужна ли запятая перед "и"? Мне кажется, что не нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, запятая не нужна: это два однородных придаточных предложения, подчинённых главной части ***он прекрасно знает***.

[Здесь](https://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37410.php) есть правило и пример:

> Если две однородные части соединены неповторяющимся соединительным или разделительным союзом, то между частями запятая не ставится: *Добрый и глупый заяц надеялся, что за зиму они с лисой подружатся и что она уже не захочет есть ближайшего соседа и лучшего друга.*

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я тоже так думала)

Comment: Не за что, Нара)